# Return Output from SQL Function using command line SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Function that returns an Integer as the Output. I need to execute it via sqlcmd and I only want to get it's integer output.

However right now I'm getting back this type of output:

```
------------ 
      25 

<1 rows affected>
```

How can I get my output to be just 25 with no other text.

Here's the Call I'm using:

```
sqlcmd -S MyServer\Instance -d SQLAdmin -Q "SELECT dbo.UDF_INT_Get_Status ('INT_02')"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the headers option of [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx). Adding `-h -1` will suppress header information.

```
sqlcmd -S MyServer\Instance -d SQLAdmin -Q "SELECT dbo.UDF_INT_Get_Status ('INT_02')" -h -1
```